# Google Books crashes on loading - workaround? (HTC Desire Z 2.3)

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, htc-desire-z, crashes, google-play-books

Google Books Android crashes on loading.

Is there a workaround to stop this, while I wait for the developers to fix?

> The application Books (process com.google.android.apps.books) has
>   stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

This happens every time (trying again won't help).

Restart of the phone and uninstall re-install of the app doesn't help either.

Apparently, there is a [known issue](http://support.google.com/books/bin/static.py?page=known_issues.cs&ki_topic=28731) whereby it will crash if it has no books (wouldn't that be most people to begin with!?)

But their remedy instructions are vague - just open a free ebook - but from what? A browser? Will this interact with Google Books to solve the problem? I visited the book store and downloaded an ebook but this just went to the Downloads folder so not sure how this can help.

I also tried copying an ebook from the Download folder to `data\com.google.android.apps.books\files` and running the Google Books app but this doesn't work - i.e. the crash still happens.

Comment: And is this still happening? If it was a known bug I suspect they've probably fixed it by now.

Comment: I've been having this problem for a few months.  Time doesn't seem to be doing the trick for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is time; an update to this app fixes this bug.

Answer (score -1):

To get around this problem is very simple. Do these actions:

1. Use your web browse on the Android device and go to website "books.google.com/ebooks"
2. Pick and download any sample book (click on Get Sample)

Once you have saved a sample book you will be able to successfully launch the Books application without the process error.

Good luck

Comment: Yup, your answer is exactly the same as their solution which doesn't work for me at the moment, as I have explained.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, and fixed it by opening a preview of a different book first. After that, I could open the other books too. Make sure you open it from within the Play Store app, and not from Google Books.